# Should I remove errors displaying from console?

Tags: reactjs, browser, console.log

I am learning error handling in a social media app using the MERN stack. I am able to easily send any errors that occur from the backend and display them in the frontend using try-catch. However, the browser console is also displaying the errors. Is it okay to show these errors in the console or is it better to suppress them?

I am having difficulty understanding this concept. I think it would be frustrating for users to see errors in the console.

Comment: Ordinary users won't see the console. Web dev users may, and may think your site is slightly inelegant as a result, but that's not really much of a deal... you even see it on many large professional sites often. But it's nice to try to avoid it for the production build.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeip. That's exact answer I was searching for. I have seen these professional sites generating errors in console & I thought it was their mistake to do this. But as you clarified, its not really important to care about unless it leaks some sensitive information. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's ok to console log the errors in front end console unless it doesn't show any important data

-You can open any social media app like (discord) for example it shows all the errors that happen while making request between the front end and the back end

*Side note: For any input or form or any entry data it's not recommended to console log these data Or you can just delete all the console logs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My app actually doesn't include sensitive info in errors so its not to worry I guess.

Comment: you are welcome <3, and yes this is normal behavior if some errors occur while sending requests between frontend and backend the errors will appear in the console,
Have fun and Good luck : )